# How to edit highstocks.js for 2 datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, highcharts, datepicker

I have a page a.jsp on which i have included b.jsp and c.jsp

`b.jsp` has a highstock graph with a date range.
`c.jsp` also has a highstock graph with a date range.

this is how i set my datepiceker

```
function(chart) {
   setTimeout(function() {
        $('input.highcharts-range-selector',$('#'+ options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
   }, 0);
});
```

and this is how i get its values on select in highcharts

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({
                    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                    onSelect : function(dateText) {
                        var from = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').val();
                        var to = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(1)') .val();
                        alert(to +"---"+from );
                        alert(from +"+==="+to);

 http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/
```

what i need to do is to get `datepicker` values from both the datepicker but i m always getting the values of first datepicker as the name is same.in both the case 
i need to change the js so that it works fine and gives me both the dates
i have copied the js for 2 page but its not working also i changed the element name in 2nd js **highcharts-range-selector** but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines:

```
var from = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').val();
var to = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(1)') .val();
```

will give you dates from first dateticker, since you have choosed 0 and 1 indexes. If you want more of them, just use:

```
var from = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').val();
var to = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(1)') .val();
var from2 = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(3)').val(); //third picker
var to2 = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(4)') .val(); //fourth picker
```

Or event better (faster):

```
var inputs = $('input.highcharts-range-selector'),
    from = inputs[0].value, //first picker
    to = inputs[1].value, //second picker
    from2 = inputs[2].value, //third picker
    to2 = inputs[3].value; //fourth picker
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/175/

Comment: i appreciate the answer but in my case i have to fetch data from 2 diffrent urls according to the date range.as i have 2 diffrent pages

Comment: can i set renderTo option at runtime??so that if i call same datepicker i can set data in diffrent div accordingly

Comment: Set? Or change? In general, you can't change that. If you have two pages, then how do you want to get info from different page? :D

Comment: i have a page in which i have included 2 jsp page both the pages get data from a url, and render to 2 diffrent div but when date is changes onSelect from datepicker jquery is called which is same for the case where i call my options part and series option part again to draw chart in that part i need to change that renderTo option or suggest how can i draw 2 datepicker getter function in jquery linked with both the datepickers diffrently

Comment: Could you use some punctuation in your description? Honestly it's hard to understand what you have, what you want, and what you expect from me. My solution doesn't depend on number of charts. See my example, it works fine. That info you have something in .jsp file, doesn't change anything.

Comment: `page 1: a.jsp` It has a list of elements: x, y, z on-click =call a method that will redirect to another page(`b.jsp`) with the element selected "  `page 2: b.jsp` draw high-stock chart with value got from a.jsp .It has a list of elements: x, y, z same as page a.jsp on-click = "call a method that will append data to another page(b.jsp) with the element selected" ( * * keep on appending on click in chart * * )this is what my code does.b.jsp page also has a chart (b)below this chart (which i made before)in chart b i hv to get date and get data from  a url based on that date whc m nt getng

Comment: So each time you add new chart to the `b.jsp` page? Then what is the problem with my solution?

Comment: my datepicker always gives me values from the first one i.e in both the cases only same datepicker is getting called

Comment: this is how i have called `$.datepicker.setDefaults({  dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',onSelect : function(dateText) {`

Comment: can you make changes to this such that u pass date to the the url from which u get json and it gets data according to that http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/175/

Comment: Yes, I can code everything for you, but this is not how it works. How do you pass actually data to the URLs? Do the same with dates from datepickers..

Comment: yeah i have done that, i m gettting dates in datepicker coloumn `to = inputs[1].value, //second picker
                from2 = inputs[2].value, //third picker
                to2 = inputs[3].value; //fourth picker

` as u said then i need to make chart ,if i get value from frist then i have to make 1 chart if from 2nd then 2nd so how do i manage so that both are created

Comment: So after you changed values in Highcharts inputs, you want to create new charts? Or you need to determine which of datepickers was changed?

Comment: i need to detrmine the date chosen and pass it back to my url

Comment: what is the response type in http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback= json ??application/json ?

Comment: It's JSONP, so it's application/json. How do you pass actually data to the url? Do the same with values from datepickers..

Comment: i have founded the solution :) thanks @Pawel fus but few more problmes are still in queue